# Applying semver on mono-repo node js projects

Tags: node.js, github, monorepo, semantic-versioning, git-tag

I have used `npx semantic-release` for tagging projects in GitHub. I am currently working on a project that uses a mono-repo layout, something like:

mono-repo

- api
- web
- mobile

I'd like to generate tags/releases separated each per component. I am not quite sure about how the tagging mechanism should work in this case. I was thinking about addiing logic to identify which component has been updated and generate a tag prefixing the component name like `mobile-1.0.1`, `api-1.2.1`, etc... Does anybody have previous experience working on something similar?

I was also thinking about creating a separate repo, each per component and from there everything will be easier to manage, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the way to go it's lerna. I found out this library pretty useful in these cases. https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/version

If you guys are using any other different approach, I'd like to know about any other alternative

Comment: Any tool that commits SemVer version strings to the repo, is broken by design. Well, they aren't very scalable. You can make it work if there is only one process that can change those values, such as the official build machine, but that doesn't scale to parallel/distributed builds, and it doesn't prevent devs from triggering those build steps locally, and polluting the version history the next time they push. And then there's the problem that for a given commit Id, there can be many builds, some of them successful, and possibly built in different environments.

Comment: No two packages, should ever have the same SemVer version string attached to them, and it is nearly impossible to build exactly the same thing, even if tooling and source code are held constant. I have worked on attempts to achieve deterministic builds, and while there's been a lot of good tooling changes towards that goal, there's still a very long list of tools that are not deterministic.

Comment: I have an example up and running here. Let me know what you guys think about it https://github.com/enriquezrene/lerna-mono-repo-semver/